Does Windows OS 'display layout scale' matter while desigining websites?
I was designing a website in Figma and after fializing the looks I copied all the CSS settings (using VS Code extension) and opened the locally hosted webpage in my browser.
What I noticed was that the design looks good when previewed in figma, but the elements looked scaled-up than in the hosted webpage. Finally found the cause for this being Windows display setting scale and layout being set to 125%.
If I set my browser scale to 80% the design looks the same as I made in Figma.
My concern is that 125% scale is a default behaviour for most devices (mainly laptops). So, should I design considering that 125% scale, or neglect it?
Windows display settings:

Figma Prototype Design:

Webpage at Windows scale:100% AND browser-zoom:100% - looks same:

Webpage at Windows scale:125% AND browser-zoom:100% - looks different:
(Notice envelope is out of frame at bottom)

Webpage at Windows scale:125% AND browser-zoom:80% - looks same (Note 1.25 * 0.8 = 1.0):


I also found this, but don't understand the answer, nor did it work for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8CV9wOuu2c
